# Wildfly json-formatter class name metadata

Tags: json, logging, jboss, wildfly

Is it possible to configure a non-static value for the metadata field in the wildly json-formatter?
I didn't find anything about it in the wildfly documentation- it only has a simple static field example (meta-data=[@version=1])

For example, I would like to have a field "simpleClassName" - The class of the code calling the log method.

I also tried to use a similar syntax to pattern-formatter(example below) but it doesn't work

```
        <formatter name="JSON">
            <json-formatter>
                <meta-data>
                    <property name="simpleClassName" value="%c{1}"/>
                </meta-data>
            </json-formatter>
        </formatter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the meta-data is only static information. However what you're looking for seems to be the details of the caller. Note that this is an expensive operation should you should use it with caution. What you'd want to do is change the `print-details` to `true`. In CLI it would be something like:

```
/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=JSON:write-attribute(name=print-details, value=true)
```